# escape comma in ruby URI::HTTP library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, net-http

I'm using URI::HTTP library to build a URL I need to use to send to an endpoint.

```
ids = "12345,54504"

uri = URI::HTTP.build({
  :host => HOST,
  :path => '/endpoint',
  :query => {
    :ids => ids
  }.to_query,
})
```

The issue I am having is that the endpoint is expecting `ids` to be comma-separated. However, the URL that this builds replaces the comma with %2C.  How do I get the url to just send the comma and not encode it.

Comment: Maybe you should pass it via json body?

Comment: `%2C` is the URL-encoded version of a comma. It is a universally valid and standard way to use a comma character in a query parameter, just as `%20` is the correct way to encode a space. The API endpoint should have no trouble decoding this correctly. If it can't, you should get in touch with the API provider so they can fix their API.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry the `%2C` is the URL-encoded of the comma.

You can try to create a route in your rails application and puts `params[:ids]`, you will see your ids with the coma.